# Why MySQL query is not using index?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Here is my problem. Query with constants in `in` list is using index

```
explain select date, serial from Statistics
where serial in ('qwe', 'asd');

# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1, SIMPLE, Statistics, range, serial, serial, 257, , 2, Using where
```

Query with `select` in `in` list is not

```
explain select date, serial from Statistics
where serial in (select serial from tmp_stats);

# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1, PRIMARY, Statistics, ALL, , , , , 339541476, Using where
2, DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, tmp_stats, ALL, , , , , 10, Using where
```

What may cause this behavior?

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `Statistics` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `serial` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `serial` (`serial`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=355592619 DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii;


CREATE TABLE `tmp_stats` (
  `date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `soft_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `serial` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  KEY `serial` (`serial`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

Comment: @AbdulManaf same problem

Comment: Abdul is correct - a join is far more likely to use an index than the IN statement - MySQL does not do push predicates. If a query with a join is not working then publish the details including the cardinality of the indexes.